# what is the meaning of threefold miseries?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Chapter 2 -- Verse 56

[source](http://bhagvadgitaa.blogspot.com/2012/06/bhagavad-gita-chapter-2-verse-56.html)

Verse: duhkhesv anudvigna-manah
sukhesu vigata-sprhah
vita-raga-bhaya-krodhah
sthita-dhir munir ucyate

Translation: "One who is not disturbed in mind even amidst the threefold miseries or elated when there is happiness, and who is free from attachment, fear and anger, is called a sage of steady

My question: what  is the  meaning  of threefold miseries ?

Comment: Related answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38187/4732

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked three translations of Gita 2.56. None of the translators uses the term threefold miseries in translating the verse. However, Sri Sankaracharya talks about threefold miseries in his commentary.

> Whose mind is not agitated in adversity, who is free from desire and
> who is devoid of attachments, fear and anger - such a person is called
> a sage of steady wisdom.

**Gita 2.56 translated by Swami Tapasyananda**

> He whose mind is untroubled in the midst of sorrows and is free from
> eager desire amid pleasures, he from whom passion, fear and rage have
> passed away, he is called a sage of settled intelligence.

**Gita 2.56 by Radhakrishnan**

> The silent sage is said to have stable wisdom when sufferings no
> longer perturb his mind, when he ceases to cling to pleasures, and he
> is rid of attachment, fear and wrath.

**Gita 2.56 of Sri Sankaracharaya translated by Dr. A. G. Krishna Warrier**

What is **Tapatraya** (three miseries)?

> **Adhibhautika**, **adhidaivika** and **adhyatmika** are known as **Tapatraya**.
>
> The three words respectively mean: pertaining to (a) the bhuta or
> living beings; (b) the daiva or fate, unseen forces and gods; (c) the
> body (and the mind).
>
> Sorrow and suffering (duhkha, tapa) are inevitable in life. In fact,
> they are a part of life. A knowledge of their origin, causes and even
> categorisation helps one to minimise their effect if not eradicate
> them. The Hindu religious works usually call them 'tapatraya', 'the
> three miseries'. They are: **adhyatmika**, **adhidaivika** and **adhibhautika**.
>
> The **adhyatmika** duhkha or tapa is that which is caused by bodily
> suffering and mental anguish. Hereditary diseases like leprosy,
> disabilities like blindness or lameness and diseases caused by the
> violation of the rules of health and sanitation are classed under
> this. The mental agony caused by worries and anxieties, attachment and
> aversion, also comes under this group.
>
> The **adhidaivika** duhkha or tapa is that which is caused by daiva. The
> word daiva includes the power of time, nature and the unseen hand of
> fate. Diseases caused by the changing seasons, misery caused by the
> elemental forces like floods and fire, suffering caused by black magic
> or gods who are displeased, natural tribulations due to hunger, thirst
> and old-age belong to this group.
>
> The **adhibhautika** duhkha or tapa is that which is caused by other
> bhutas or living beings, like wild animals, snakes or enemies.
>
> Some of these, like hereditary diseases or physical disabilities
> cannot be got rid of. Hence they must be endured. Some like the
> diseases caused by change of seasons or the machinations of enemies
> can be countered by taking appropriate precautions. However, raising
> the mind to the level of the spirit, thus transcending the limitations
> imposed by the body-mind complex, is the best solution to offset the
> effects of tapatraya.

**A Concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**

Comment: see the link provided by nitaigaursevak

Answer (score 3):

The threefold miseries mentioned in this particular translation refers to - adhyatmika (misery due to one's own body and mind), adhibhautika (misery due to other living entities) and adhidaivika (misery due to nature).

You can refer to this site for more understanding, it contains commentaries of BG from all the major Acharyas of different sampradayas - https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-2-56/